# Numbering values based on the appearance of a certain value in a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with over 1000 rows and multiple columns. Here is a part of it:

```
structure(list(level = c(5, 6, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 5, 8, 
5, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like this

```
   level
   <dbl>
 1     5
 2     6
 3     8
 4     6
 5     7
 6     8
 7     7
 8     8
 9     7
10     8
11     5
12     8
13     5
14     8
15     5
16     8
17     8
18     8
```

How can I generate a unique id that changes as soon as a 5 appears. The result would look like this:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 2
   level    id
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     5     1
 2     6     1
 3     8     1
 4     6     1
 5     7     1
 6     8     1
 7     7     1
 8     8     1
 9     7     1
10     8     1
11     5     2
12     8     2
13     5     3
14     8     3
15     5     4
16     8     4
17     5     5
18     8     5
```

In a second step I would like to id the next level based on the level before and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Use a cumulative summation

```
someframe <- structure(list(level = c(
  5, 6, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 5, 8,
  5, 8, 5, 8, 5, 8
)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))


someframe$id <- cumsum(someframe$level == 5)

someframe
```

```
> someframe
   level id
1      5  1
2      6  1
3      8  1
4      6  1
5      7  1
6      8  1
7      7  1
8      8  1
9      7  1
10     8  1
11     5  2
12     8  2
13     5  3
14     8  3
15     5  4
16     8  4
17     5  5
18     8  5
```

Comment: I changed the question a little bit (wanted to have the next level acording to the level above. This can be done as follows:


mydata %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(level == 5)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(id2 = cumsum(level == 6)) %>% 
  group_by(id, id2) %>% 
  mutate(id3 = cumsum(level == 7)) %>% 
  group_by(id, id2, id3) %>% 
  mutate(id3 = cumsum(level == 8))